# UIPrinterCutterBehavior delegate method never called

Tags: objective-c, xcode, printing, uiprintinteractioncntrler

I have a simple iOS application that prints out receipts to a STAR-TSP650II AirPrint printer. The prints are successful, but I need the jobs to be printed on 1 page, seeing as it's a receipt.. and the printer is capable of doing so. There are 2 delegate methods for AirPrint which are:

```
- (CGFloat)printInteractionController:(UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController 
                cutLengthForPaper:(UIPrintPaper *)paper;
- (UIPrinterCutterBehavior)printInteractionController:(UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController 
                             chooseCutterBehavior:(NSArray *)availableBehaviors;
```

I can't get these methods to be called. I've tried putting breakpoints and logs in the methods to see if they're called, but no. Here is my code:

```
#pragma mark    -   Print:

- (void)printReceipt:(UIPrinter *)printer {

    NSURL *receiptURL                           =   [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myurl.com/printer"];
    UIPrintInteractionController *controller    =   [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    [controller setDelegate:self];
    [controller setPrintInfo:[UIPrintInfo printInfo]];
    [controller setPrintingItem:receiptURL];

    //  contact:
    [printer contactPrinter:^(BOOL available) {

        //  print:
        [controller printToPrinter:printer completionHandler:^(UIPrintInteractionController * _Nonnull printInteractionController, BOOL completed, NSError * _Nullable error) {



        }];

    }];

}

- (CGFloat)printInteractionController:(UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController cutLengthForPaper:(UIPrintPaper *)paper {
    NSLog(@"this never gets called.");
    return CGFLOAT_MAX;
}
- (UIPrinterCutterBehavior)printInteractionController:(UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController chooseCutterBehavior:(NSArray *)availableBehaviors {
    NSLog(@"this never gets called either.");
    return UIPrinterCutterBehaviorCutAfterEachJob;
}
```

Comment: You say that your printer supports cutting. But does the Airprint driver support cutting with this printer?

Comment: Yeah, there's an app called iZettle, I've used it with the same printer and they're able to cut it when needed. For now, I'm going to pull apart their app to see how they do it

Comment: Okay.. here's an update; the delegate methods get called when using a simulated label printer (in the Printer Simulator.app).. but still never gets called on the real AirPrint printer (STAR TSP650II)

Comment: Seems like you have done everything right on your end. You should file a bug report on bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer to my question.

It must be STAR that haven't configured their printer with AirPrint properly.

They have 2 iOS SDK's; Standard and Legacy.. the Legacy SDK has all the functions I need to cut the paper. If you come across something like this, see if the manufacturer has an SDK for AirPrint.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue with that Star printer. Were you able to resolve this with AirPrint or did you have to use the Star SDK?

Comment: Yes! It's been over a year since I worked with printers, so please excuse my inability to remember exactly how it was that I resolved it.. but I did write a class helper called `MPManager` that ended up working flawlessly which is on my repo: https://github.com/iosdec/MPManager hope it helps you 

Comment: @PabloRomero this also helps with printing out multiple jobs in AirPrint which was really annoying that it didn't support this already. I think `MPManager` supports EPSON, STAR and AirPrint. Please also feel free to contribute to it if you feel it could be improved! 

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look.

Comment: @PabloRomero you're welcome, let me know how you get on with it - curious to see if it solves your problem 

Answer (score -1):

The class/Controller in which you wrote protocol/delegate method, try this

```
[self setDelegate:controller];
```

and tell me if its not working.

Comment: that definitely doesn't work, the class I'm using is something I've made called "MPManager" which has it's own delegate property